# How do I pass cell value to variable

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel Sheet Data :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhwwW.png]

I want to pass the values of Highlighted yellow Data to my code which is below

My actually code

```
DB connectivity details. 
      DBHost = B1
      DBPort = B2
      DBsid =  B3
      DBuid =  B4
      DBpwd =  B5
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Looks ok to me.

Comment: If "not working" means you get an error, please [edit] your question and include the error message and in which line you get the error. If it means nothing happens then explain what exactly did you expect to happen and how did you test it?

Comment: Your code looks ok, maybe try to use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")` instead of `ActiveSheet` you might try to get data from a non active sheet else you code seems working nicely, if this didn't solve your issue please add further information !

Comment: @Dorian I have updated my question pls look

Comment: @SJR I have updated my question pls look

Comment: @deltofukno I think you need to use an array and not a dim

Comment: @deltofukno This is a very very basic and common task did you even research "how to read cell values in VBA"? Please see: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like I didn't understood your question So there is 2 Answer possible

The First one Which will be the most basic

```
Sub Tryme()

Dim DBHost As String
Dim DBPortAs String
Dim DBsid As String
Dim DBuid As String
Dim DBpwd As String

 DBHost = Range("B1").Value
 DBPort = Range("B2").Value
 DBsid =  Range("B3").Value
 DBuid =  Range("B4").Value
 DBpwd =  Range("B5").Value

End Sub
```

And the Second one which will use an Array

```
Sub Tryme()
    lastrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Dim MyArray()
    ReDim MyArray(lastrow - 1, 2)
For i = 0 To lastrow - 1
    MyArray(i, 0) = Range("A" & i + 1)
    MyArray(i, 1) = Range("B" & i + 1)
Next
End Sub
```

The **Output** Of the array would be :

[image]

So for exemple :

`debug.print MyArray(0,0)` would give **DBHost**

`debug.print MyArray(0,1)` would give **"h##123demo"**

And so on
**EDIT** based On @PeH 's Comment :

```
Sub test()

Dim MyArray() As Variant

lastrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
MyArray = Range("A1", "B" & lastrow).Value


End Sub
```

Comment: Note that how you read the array can be done in one line instead of a loop: `MyArray = Range("A1", "B" & LastRow).Value` reads the whole range into an array at once, you just need to `Dim MyArray() As Variant` no `ReDim` at all.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for giving me better insight, You definitly improve my level :D

Comment: @Pᴇʜ How can I debug.print this ? (First Time I do like that) so i guess it would be better if I can explain the OP how to get the value stored in this array

Comment: You can't you need to loop for outputting a 2D array. A one-dimensional array can be outputted using `Join()`.